# Unable to add code to a new thread and return string

Tags: java, android, mysql

I have a method called receive data which can successfully log onto MySQL database and retrieve data from database, however i am unable to return that data out of the method to display in text view on android app. When i have it running in a thread which android forces me to do i cant return a value as string and when its not in thread it wont execute on the main thread so I'm not sure how to get around this by adding it into a separate thread and also returning the string value out of the method to be used in the text view.
you will see i have commented out some of my attempts to resolve so at the moment
the value I'm trying to return is response.toString() which works fine until i add it to a separate thread let me know what other code elements i need to add for more information, i don't want to add it all just here and confuse the question.

```
package com.example.scottysmith;


import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.ProtocolException;
import java.net.URL;

public class GetData  extends Thread  {



    public String RecieveData(String link) {

        GetData thread = new GetData();
         thread.start();


        // Thread outputdata = new Thread(() -> {


        // try {


        URL url = null;
        try {
            url = new URL(link);
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
        try {
            assert url != null;

            urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        //urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
        assert urlConnection != null;
        urlConnection.setDoInput(true);
        // urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
        //urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
        //urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content- Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        //urlConnection.setRequestProperty("charset", "UTF-8");
        //urlConnection.connect();
        //urlConnection.getOutputStream();
        // urlConnection.getResponseCode();
        try {
            urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
        } catch (ProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }



                /*JSONObject data = new JSONObject();
                data.put("name", name);
                data.put("surname", surname);
                data.put("location", location);

                OutputStreamWriter wr = new OutputStreamWriter(urlConnection.getOutputStream());
                wr.write(String.valueOf(data));
                wr.flush();
                wr.close();*/

        BufferedReader in = null;
        try {
            in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(urlConnection.getInputStream()));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        String inputLine = null;
        StringBuilder response = new StringBuilder();

        while (true) {
            try {
                assert in != null;
                if ((inputLine = in.readLine()) == null) break;
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            response.append(inputLine);


        }


        try {
            in.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        //return response.toString();
        System.out.println(response);


        //   } catch (Exception e) {
        //    e.printStackTrace();
        // }
        // });


        // }


        // );

        // outputdata.start();
        return response.toString();
    }




}
```

Comment: Calling the thread.start() does nothing.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you write the value you want to return to a variable. Then in your run method you call the RecieveData method.
This will write the value you want to a variable "returnValue".
which you can access after the thread ends.

```
public class GetData  extends Thread  {
    private String returnValue;
    private String link;
    public GetData(String link){
    this.link = link;
    }

    private void RecieveData() {
          //some code here;
          //Do not create new Thread here. 
          
          returnValue = response.toString();
    }
    
    @Override
    public void run(){
          RecieveData();
    }

    public String getAnswer(){
          return returnValue;
    }
}
```

Do not create new thread in the ReceiveData method. Create the new thread from your main thread and instead of calling the receiveData function you should call the start() on the thread.

Remember to call the `thread.join()` method after starting the thread before calling the `getAnswer()` method. This will make the main wait for the thread to end before reading from the returnValue.
I hope this helps.

```
/*
Inside the main thread
*/
     GetData data = new GetData("Your link here");
     data.start();
     data.join();
     String myAnswer = data.getAnswer();
```

Comment: HI Isaac, thank you very much for the swift response, i will try implement these changes later and advise i really appreciate the help.

Comment: Hi Isaac, thank you i made the changes and all is able to run without exception however when i check the value of returnValue in the get answer method its null, in Receive data its = to my value from from the data base.

Comment: ok nevermind i called the method at the wrong point it worked thank you very much

Comment: sorry for the late reply. Happy to have helped

Comment: HI Isaac, i was hoping you can help me with 1 more thing please, so the response from my API is actually in Json Array, here is what it looks like: Array[{"Unique":"1","Available_Funds":"100","Current_Month_Spend":"100","Previous_Month_Spend":"50"}] , so at the moment its displays as is which is not ideal i actually want to interpret it as Json and use the keys and values but im also struggling with this now, can you help? let me know if i must post a new question or what

Comment: @Ash27 please post the full question and send me the link via nisaacdz@gmai.com